# How to fix negative magnitude in 2D Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-physics

I've build a simple 2D project in Unity and trying to implement kinematic physics. I'm getting negative magnitude for moving vector, and i want to know why.

[image]

The collider right on the edge of walls, but i don't understand how exactly it can affect a private variable

Move method called in FixedUpdate

```
private void Move(Vector2 destination)
{
    // destination: "(0.0, -0.1)"

    float distance = destination.magnitude;
    // destination: "(0.0, -0.1)"   distance: -0.00999999978

    if (distance > MinMoveDistance)
    {
        int count = rigidbody2D.Cast(destination, hitBuffer, distance + ShellRadius);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            Vector2 currentNormal = hitBuffer[i].normal;

            if (Mathf.Approximately(currentNormal.y, 1f)) 
            {
                IsGrounded = true;
            }

            float modifiedDistance = hitBuffer[i].distance - ShellRadius;

            distance = modifiedDistance < distance ? modifiedDistance : distance;
        }
    }

    rigidbody2D.position = rigidbody2D.position + destination.normalized * distance;
}
```

Comment: At what point in your code are you checking the value of `distance`? If you're checking it literally right after assigning it then there's no way that it's a negative value. I suspect you're checking it at a later time (most likely **after** it is changed via the `modifiedDistance` block of code lower down).

Comment: It's pretty obvious that distance isn't negative there because you're going inside the `if (distance > MinMoveDistance)` block. You're not accurately describing the situation.

Answer (score 0):

`float distance = destination.magnitude;` should always return a positive number, not sure how you are getting the values you have provided in your comments.

Regardless, if you want to ensure that `distance` is always positive, simply use
`float distance = Mathf.Abs(destination.magnitude);`

Comment: `float distance = Mathf.Abs(destination.magnitude);` returns same result, but something like this 
`float a = distance;  
a = Mathf.Abs(a);  
// a:  0.00999999978 
`
weird stuff